# How to Splitting Comma-Separated Values from table1 to table2 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have table t1 values store in "," separated
Table t1

```
id  value
1   d3,d8,d3,d1
2   t1,t2,d3,d8
3    t2,d1
```

I want to copy all data in another table t2 like using mysql query 
Expected result

```
Table t2
id    key
1     d3
2     d8
3     d1
```

Comment: And how did you choose those three values for `t2`?

Comment: Unclear. Please provide a complete output of the result and/or a more detailed description of the copy algorithm.

Comment: This kind of schema violates the 
[Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so I hope for your sake this is a first step towards undoing that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `explode()` function in PHP.
You'll get an array which will have a structure like this `array_key => array_value`.

Example:

```
$values = "d3,d8,d3,d1";
$values_array = explode(",", $values);
print_r($values_array);
```

"," is the delimiter.

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => d3 [1] => d8 [2] => d3 [3] => d1 )
```

However you'll need to get the values from the database first.

Source:
[Function - explode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)